# Async.waterfall returning async

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, node-async

I am trying to use [`async.waterfall`](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall) to create a response in my [`express`](http://expressjs.com/) services.  Here is my code:

```
var getUserObject = function(id, res) {
  'use strict';
  async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
      getCompleteUserObject(callback, id);
    }
  ], function(err, result) {
    res.json(result.user);
  });
  // Function returns here
};
```

I want my return statement to be the `res.json(result.user)`, but the `waterfall` function always returns where I have the commented code above.  I use `series` and `parallel` function all the time and they work find.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean that you want the return statement to be the `res.json(result.user)`? The nature of the `waterfall` call is that it's async, so, it doesn't have a result and returns immediately. `getUserObject` can't return a value that was computed in the call to `waterfall`.

Comment: What you're trying to do is an exact duplicate of [this infamous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call), only in node. You can't return the result of an async method into a variable to be used later, you have to wait for the async call to finish, and that's what callbacks are for, the async middleware is just a helper to avoid "callback hell".